# How I can store phone numbers using addressbook component ? FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I tried like this. First and Last names are added but phone number is not (Delphi 11, FMX)

```
procedure TForm1.ActionAddContactExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  Contact: TAddressBookContact;
  Phones: TContactPhones;
  eMails: TContactEmails;
  Photo: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  Contact := AddressBook1.CreateContact(FDefaultSource);
  try
    try
      Contact.FirstName := edtFirstName.Text;
      Contact.LastName := edtLastName.Text;

      Phones := TContactPhones.Create;
      try﻿
        Phones.AddPhone(TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '767867679678');
        Contact.Phones := Phones;
      finally
        Phones.Free;
      end;

      if not Image1.Bitmap.Size.IsZero then
      begin
        Photo := TBitmapSurface.Create;
        try
          Photo.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
          Contact.Photo := Photo;
          Image1.Bitmap.SetSize(0, 0);
        finally
          Photo.Free;
        end;
      end;
      // Add the work mail
      eMails := TContactEmails.Create;
      try
        eMails.AddEmail(TContactEmail.TLabelKind.Work, edtWorkMail.Text);
        Contact.eMails := eMails;
      finally
        eMails.Free;
      end;
      // Save a newly created contact to Address Book
      AddressBook1.SaveContact(Contact);

    except
      on E: EAddressBookException do
        ShowMessage('Cannot create the contact.' + E.Message);
    end;

    // Add the contact to the selected group, if any
    try
      if InRange(ComboBox1.ItemIndex, 0, FGroups.Count - 1) then
        AddressBook1.AddContactIntoGroup
          (FGroups.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex], Contact);
    except
      on E: EAddressBookException do
        ShowMessage('Cannot add the newly created contact to group.' + E.Message);
    end;

    ListViewContacts.BeginUpdate;
    try
      AddListViewItem(Contact);
    finally
      ListViewContacts.EndUpdate;
    end;
    TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItemContacts;
  finally
    Contact.Free;
  end;
  // Clear the Add Contact Form
  ClearAddContactForm;
end;
```

Comment: are you supposed to free the ``Phones`` object yourself after you added it to ``Contact``?

Comment: it should yes..

Comment: How do you conclude it didn't work?

Comment: I opened my phone book nothing but the names and the group no number

Comment: So no email address is displayed either? Can't you edit your question with the added details instead of cluttering the comments?

Comment: So don't free the ``Phones`` object and check if the number gets added then.

Comment: @DelphiCoder this solved the problem !! you can add it as answer ?

Comment: @AmigoJack if I asked to solve more than one problem , moderators will close the question. must ask to solve one problem only

Comment: same thing removing `eMails.Free;` made the email added too

Comment: Many thanks guys wish you happy holidays in this difficult times ❤️

Comment: You should still free `Phones`, `eMails` and `Photo` but make sure you only free them after calling `AddressBook1.SaveContact(Contact);`. Not freeing them will lead to memory leaks. And as you have learned freeing them to fast discards all the entered contact data before it is saved into phones Address Book

Comment: @SilverWarior but freeing them was after assign to Contact `Contact.Phones := Phones;`

Comment: `TContactPhones`, `TContactEmails` and `TBitmapSurface` are classes. Which means that when you call `Contact.Phones := Phones;` you are just assignin reference of your `Phones` class to `Contact.Phones` field. So if you then free `Phones` the `Contact.Phones` field now references nonexistent object. So I'm guessing that in such scenario `AddressBook1.SaveContact(Contact);` simply just skips over instead of raising any exception which simply results in no data being stored in phones Address Book.